# Proving whether homomorphism exists from $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$ onto $\mathbb{Z}_2 ⊕ \mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

[image]

Confused at the aforementioned proof. I understand that $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$ is completely determined by $f(1)$. But have a couple other questions.

If $f$ is onto, then $|f(1)| = 2$. Why is this the case? Is it because $1$ in $\mathbb{Z_2}$ alone has an order of 2? Not sure what I'm missing here but is that what restricts the order of $f(1)$ to being $2$? Is that also how they conclude that $f(1) = (1,0), (0,1), (1,1)$?

Additionally, we also have if $f$ is onto, $|ker(f)| = 16/4 = 4$. Is it valid to say that $|G|/|ker(f)| = |im(f)| => |ker(f)| = |G|/|im(f)| = 16/4$. And the image is 4 because that's the order of the extern direct product.

Understand the rest but just wondering how they got the values  $f(1) = (1,0), (0,1), (1,1)$.

Appreciate clarification! Thanks.

Comment: Does $|f(1)|$ denote the order of $f(1)$? If so that is horrid notation.

Comment: If $f(1)=(0,0)$ then $f(x)=(0,0)$ for all $x$ so $f$ certainly isn't surjective.

Comment: Yeah, it denotes the order.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$ actually has four elements altogether: $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$. $f(1)$ cannot be $(0,0)$ as this would map every element into the identity - thus $f(1)$ must be one of the other three elements. It isn't any more profound than that.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!